# how to Change charactors encode in php or html?

Tags: php, html, text, character-encoding

i have text in English and Windows-1256 (Arabic Language) and when i print the file containing the text with php, the file has miss interrupted and i get this

*ط± ظ„ظ„ط·ظٹط±ط§ظط± ظ„ظ„ط·ظٹط±ط§ظ*

Comment: Maybe this article can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674121/arabic-character-encoding-issue-utf-8-versus-windows-1256 :-)

Comment: thank you @C0dekid this solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @C0dekid
I just added

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html'; charset='UTF-8'/>
```

and it solved my problem.